# Xamarin Forms navigation page back to tab out of tabbed context

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a main page that I create in the App class of the shared Xamarin.Forms app like so:

```
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

In that main page, I make it tabbed and create two children:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.Children.Add(new FirstPage());
        this.Children.Add(new SecondPage());
    }
}
```

FirstPage has a click handler that sends you to a ThirdPage:

```
TheButton.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ThirdPage());
};
```

As expected, the third page has a back button, but when I click it, it returns me to the FirstPage out of the context of the tabbed page. In other words, I'm not back in the child of the tabbed page, but the individual child page with no way to get back to the tabs.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Is your 'FirstPage' a NavigationPage or just a ContentPage?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Navigation Page from your Main Page.

```
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

Add Navigation Page to both of your child pages.

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new FirstPage())
        {
            Title = "First Page", 
            Icon = "FirstIcon.png" 
        });
        this.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new SecondPage())
        {
            Title = "Schedule", 
            Icon = "Schedule.png" 
        });
    }
}
```

For further information reference: https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-tabbedpage-navigation-recipe/

Comment: This doesn't work on Android. The tabs are still visible from ThirdPage.

Comment: What happen when you `Navigation.PopToRootAsync();`?